# operator precedence using list in java

Tags: java, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

i need some help in our assignment. im trying to create a program that will compute using operator precedence. if it is possible, i want to compute the expression inside an arraylist. for ex. [4+2x2-3] should calculate 2x2 first so the result will be [4+4-3] and so on... my program only calculates the first operation but couldn't reiterate through others. also.. it only calculates when the highest priority operator is in the beginning. ex. [2^1-2] becomes [2-2]. but when [2-1^2] it doesn't do anything.thanks for help

```
List<String> subroutine = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(input);
        for(String i : subroutine)
    {
        switch(currentstate)
        {
            case q0:
                if(isDigit(i))
                {
                    currentstate = q1;
                }
            break;

            case q1:
                if(i.equals("^"))
                {
                    maxPriority = i;
                    int index = subroutine.indexOf(maxPriority);
                    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(subroutine.get(index-1));
                    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(subroutine.get(index+1));
                    int total = (int) Math.pow(num1, num2);

                    String stringTotal = Integer.toString(total);
                    String addToExp = subroutine.set(index, stringTotal);
                    int indexAddToExp = subroutine.indexOf(stringTotal);
                    subroutine.remove(indexAddToExp+1);
                    subroutine.remove(indexAddToExp-1);
                    System.out.println(subroutine);
                }
                else if( (i.equals("x") || i.equals("/")) && (!input.contains("^")) )
                {
                    if(i.equals("x"))
                    {
                        maxPriority = i;
                        int index = subroutine.indexOf(maxPriority);
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(subroutine.get(index-1));
                        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(subroutine.get(index+1));
                        int total = num1 * num2;

                        String stringTotal = Integer.toString(total);
                        String addToExp = subroutine.set(index, stringTotal);
                        int indexAddToExp = subroutine.indexOf(stringTotal);
                        subroutine.remove(indexAddToExp+1);
                        subroutine.remove(indexAddToExp-1);
                    }
```

Comment: You can't do this without a stack. Google for 'shunting-yard algorithm' for one way to do it.

Comment: i've already made a program using shunting yard algorithm postfix. but im confused with this infix notation.

Comment: Infix notation is what you already have. What's to be confused about?

Answer (score 4):

You should consider building up a more complex structure of expressions than simply using a Collection of strings.

Basically you will want to parse the given arithmetic expression into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) based on a given [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which could roughly look like this:

```
ArithmethicExpression := CompoundExpression | LiteralExpresion
LiteralExpression := {0-9}+ (meaning at least one digit)
CompoundExpression := LiteralExpression FunctionExpression LiteralExpression
```

This grammar is just a rough idea of what you need, but certainly it will help you to make it easier for you to implement what you need.

There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form), which is clearly related. Especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422825/1251613) answer is really interesting for you.

Comment: im sorry but, i dont really understand it. lol

Comment: A regular grammar won't do it. He needs a context-free grammar to handle precedence.

Comment: @EJP I think you are right. At least hinting to some formal grammar is helpful. I will edit the answer.